# Как отцентровать блоки в последней строке грида, при условии, что блок динамичный и количество элементов может меняться?

Tags: html, css, scss

Как отцентровать блоки в последней строке грида, при условии, что блок динамичный и количество элементов может меняться?
Собственно, интересует, есть ли вообще такое решение у грида, не рассматривая вариант с флексами вообще. Ниже пример сетки.

[image: пример сетки]

Comment: Конечно, делаете 4 колонны, 5-ый элемент делаете пустым и ставите `gap` +- 20 пикселей.

Comment: Можно пример кода? Не очень Вас поняла

Comment: Вам предлагают добавить пустой пятый элемент.

Comment: Читать значит больше надо. Читайте про свойство `grid-template-columns`. Пятый элемент делается пустым, чтобы было пустое место перед 6-м элементом.

Comment: Я попросила пример кода, Вы же просто нагрубили)  Каким образом в адаптивной верстке ДИНАМИЧНОГО блока, заполняемого, например, посредством wordpress это решение имеет место быть? Это больше похоже на костыль, чем на решение

Comment: @АлександраИванова вы не разобрались в теме, в том же MDN допустим, можно прочитать [как использовать grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout) и там применяется `grid-template-columns` (я читал английскую версию, не знаю как дела обстоят с русским). P.S. [русская версия](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout) также присутствует

Comment: Я понимаю о чем вы говорите, grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr) даст нам сетку из 4 элементов, но выравниваться они будут ПО СЕТКЕ, и нижние два будут прибиты к левому краю, соответственно. При неизвестном количестве блоков, например, карточек товаров - мы не можем добавлять пустые элементы

Comment: @АлександраИванова так, теперь приступим к другой части моего сообщения, зачем я по вашему просил добавить 5-ый элемент, который будет пустой? (то-есть без стилей, текста и проч.)

Comment: Ваш вариант сработает, только если при такой сетке количество элементов в нижней строке будет равно 2, но что, если оно будет равно 3 или 1?

Comment: @АлександраИванова мдам, оказывается условия задачи теперь пишется в заголовке...

Comment: "блок динамичный и количество элементов может меняться" - это цитата из вопроса :)

Comment: Я впервые на сайте, если вы посмотрите профиль. Грубить у Вас получается лучше, чем читать)

Comment: @АлександраИванова ладно, какое поведение вы ожидаете при 3 или том же 1-м блоке?

Comment: @ΝNL993 центрирование нижних блоков по горизонтальной оси, которого можно добиться, к примеру, флексами. Но меня интересует, возможно ли добиться гридами

Comment: @АлександраИванова хм, без точного указания кол-ва элементом такого не добиться (как я знаю), не думаю что Grid вам подходит в данной задаче.

Comment: Для этой задачи нужно тонну javascript написать, что бы были условия, если блоков внизу 1 или 3 то сработало одно условие, если 2 или 4 другое и т д... по моему лучше пересмотреть позицию и сделать как то по другому